# C# Trying to add items into database, getting error

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-5

I am trying to add this information into my database. My SQL Server will generate the Id for each row in the table. However, for some reason my code is adding a "0" for Id and I cannot figure out why or where it is coming from and I need to remove it so that the database can just generate it.

Here is my code:

```
 public class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {

    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "time")]
    [Required]
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
}


public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("ContactConnectionString")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Contact> ContactForm { get; set; }
}


public class ImportToDataBase
{


    public static void SubmitToDatabase(string theMessage, string fullName, string emailAddress)
    {




        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            var contact = new Contact()
            {
                Email = emailAddress,
                Message = theMessage,
                Name = fullName,
                Date = DateTime.Now.Date,
                Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay,
                // ID is not set in here
            };
            db.ContactForm.Add(contact);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try decorating your `Id` property with the following:

`[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

The `Key` attribute tells Entity Framework that the Id property is the primary key and should not be included in the insert statement.

Comment: I have tried to do that however when I switch it to Identity instead of .None I get this error. "Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: @user2958455 Are you using Azure?

Comment: Yes I am using Azure.

Comment: Not sure what the problem was. I dropped the table and then forced a migration and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you need to mark your id with Key and Identity Option.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

For fluent API you can use as:

```
 HasKey(i => i.ID);
 Property(i => i.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```